# Finite group with exactly one class each of two given groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Given two nonisomorphic finite groups, is it always possible to construct a larger finite group with exactly one conjugacy class of subgroups isomorphic to each?

Comment: I suspect that $A_5$ and $A_5 \times A_5$ might be a counterexample.

Comment: @DerekHolt What if you take the semidirect product of $A_5\times A_5$ with $\mathbb Z_2$, where the latter acts by permitting the components?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: That one is $A_5 \wr S_2$ which has three classes of subgroups isomorphic to $A_5$